# Dynamically generating single pages with Markdown files

Tags: markdown, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make single project pages in Nuxt, but I can't successfully generate any dynamic pages using markdown. I've followed the entire tutorial [here](https://nirebu.com/blog/building-my-static-blog-with-nuxtjs-and-markdown-beginner) and two things happen that are not part of the expected behavior.

1. The `<div v-html="content" class="blog-content content"></div>` renders the image below (which is not parsed correctly):
   [image]
2. When I try to access the attribute *title* in my markdown file, nothing is rendered on the screen.

Here is an example of one of the markdown files I'm using:

```
---
title: "Fresh Projects"
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I've went through a lot of tutorials online to use dynamically generated pages using markdown files, but none of the tutorials displayed the content correctly (or at all).

I'm wondering if anyone knows a good, straightforward, step-by-step way to add dynamically generated pages using markdown as slugs. Markdown is fantastic since the content I write on it generates the correct HTML in the front-end and is super useful for my profile (since I want to write a lot about each individual project I worked on in the past).

Answer (score 0):

The [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) was in conflict with [frontmatter-markdown-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/frontmatter-markdown-loader) and caused the unexpected behaviors! For any future Googlers that run into this problem, make sure to *remove* `markdown-it` and proceed with `frontmatter-markdown-loader`. Also followed this [tutorial](https://regenrek.com/posts/create-a-frontmatter-markdown-powered-blog-with-nuxt-js-in-2019/) to make everything work.

If you're interested in my solution, make sure to comment below and I will post my code!